# C# HttpClient + Cookiecontainer works on localhost fails on production

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient, cookiecontainer

I built a function that its purpose is to emulate a real browser's client surfing a website, submitting a form and receiving a result from that website.
Here is my code:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    handler.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); //Allow Fiddler
    var response = client.PostAsync(baseAddress, null).Result;
    var cookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").ToList();
    var sessionCookie = cookies[0];
    sessionCookie = sessionCookie.Split(';')[0];
    var sessionId = sessionCookie.Replace("ASP.NET_SessionId=", "");
    cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", sessionId, "/"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", 
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "http://");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "http://");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("keep-alive");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "open");

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ...
    };

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, new KeyValuePairConverter()), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    response = client.PostAsync("http://", content).Result;                        
        //Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    //IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress).Cast<Cookie>();
    //foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
    //{
    //    cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
    //}
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xhtml+xml"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/webp"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/apng"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    ***response = client.GetAsync("http://").Result;***
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
}
```

When I run this code in dibug mode from my VS 2017 - it runs perfect! after publishing to my iis8 server i get this response:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
Challenge=;
ChallengeId=;
GenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies must be enabled in order to view this page.";
</script>
<script>
function test(var1)
{
    var var_str=""+Challenge;
    var var_arr=var_str.split("");
    var LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];
    var minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];
    var subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);
    var subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+var_arr[1];
    var my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);
    var x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;
    var y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);
    var answer=x*y;
    answer-=my_pow*1;
    answer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);
    answer=answer+subvar2;
    return answer;
}
</script>
<script>
client = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        client = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    };
}
if (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))
{
    document.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are supported.<BR>");

}
else
{
    client.onreadystatechange  = function()
    {
        if(client.readyState  == 4)
        {
            var MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");
            if ((MyCookie == null) || (MyCookie==""))
            {
                document.write(client.responseText);
                return;
            }

            var cookieName = MyCookie.split('=')[0];
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)
            {
                document.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);
                return;
            }
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    };
    y=test(Challenge);
    client.open("POST",window.location,true);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-ID', ChallengeId);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-Result',y);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge',Challenge);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/plain');
    client.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>JavaScript must be enabled in order to view this page.</noscript>
</body>
</HTML>
```

What I did so far:
1. I compared my http requests using fiddler from my localhost and production server - they are identical.
2. I checked that my iis website is set to use cookies. I didn't locate the cookie files physically in the server not localhost to compare them - I didn't find them and don't know if its relevant.

Can you think of any lead to the cause / solution?

Comment: I can think of two causes to explain that you're not seeing this behavior in local: 1/ this behavior is only in release mode (you are testing in debug mode), 2/ this behavior is only in IIS (you are likely testing with IIS Express in local)

Comment: Thanks @KevinGosse. I tried running my app on release mode on my localhost - it is working. how can I check if IIS is the cause for this behavior?